# CI pipeline run only when Merge Request has new push commit and to specific branch

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I want to create a pipeline that only run when have merge request to specific branch and also it can run every time working branch has new push commit.

this is my example but it wont work properly:

```
unit_test:
stage: test
script:
 - echo "unit test running"
only:
 - merge_requests
 - develop
 - push
```

Answer (score 4):

When working with merge requests, you need to use `workflow` and `rule` to control how the runner should trigger the pipelines. You can read more about them on Gitlab's official documentation: [Gitab CI workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow) and [Gitlab CI rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif)

Using `workflow`, you can control the execution of stages generally, and using `rules` you can control the execution of a specific stage. You can use [Predefined Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) or even custom variables to write some rules.

For instance, in the following sample, the runner will trigger the pipeline if there is a push over branches and when a merge request is created. It will also disable branch pipeline when you push to a branch when there is an open merge request.

```
image: ...

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' # All branches
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"' # Merge requests
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS' # Fix detached merge request pipelines
      when: never
```

And in the following example, you can limit the execution of a stage by the name of the source and destination branches in the merge request.

```
job:
  script: echo "Hello, Rules!"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature/'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have now idea how to do what I want.
but sadly our devops team is maintaining an old gitlab version that not support workflow keyword and other.
but this will be useful in future thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

using Gitlab CI workflow and Gitlab CI rules make what i want to do.

```
image: ...

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' # All branches
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"' # Merge requests
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS' # Fix detached merge request pipelines
      when: never
```