# How to apply if else conditions in gitlab CI on merge requests?

Tags: git, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am trying to achieve the the below flow possible using gitlab CI. As I will be having multiple branches such as(dev-*, release- *, feature- *) with the will to manage them. Initially I just want to know if I can achieve this flow. I tried using an "if" statement in gitlabCI but as I have just started using it, I am not able to create and understand the features provided by gitlab.
The desire flow in gitlabCI:

```
if (MR from feature* to Dev OR MR from feature* to release)
{
  echo "Unit Testing";
  echo "Code quality analysis";
}
if (feature* MERGE to Dev)  
{
  echo "Build Docker image with tag $Build_ID";
}
if (feature* MERGE to Release:<release_version>)
{
  echo "Build docker image with $release_version"
}
```

`MR` refer to merge request.

`feature`, `dev`, `release` are branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a complete answer on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67833106/3907548), which you can check. But in summary, you can use `workflow` and `rules` to control the execution flow of the pipeline and stages. You can read more about them [Gitlab CI workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow) and [Gitlab CI rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) page.

In this case, you can use `rules` like the following example. The runner will trigger the `test` stage only if one of the following `if` statements evaluated to true.

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Unit Testing";
    - echo "Code quality analysis";
  rules:
    if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == dev' # Merge request from feature to dev
    if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == release' # Merge request from feature to release
...
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote it. Thanks.